# meteor up - mup setup deploy error on digitalocean

Tags: meteor, meteor-up, mup

Sorry for the question, but i didn't find any useful answer until now.

I am trying to follow a simple [tutorial](http://it.discovermeteor.com/chapters/deploying/) , and everything is going fine.

But when i type 'mup setup' on my local pc, I got this error:

```
Started TaskList: Setup Docker
[---.--.-.254] - Setup Docker
[---.--.-.254] x Setup Docker: FAILED

-----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
bash: line 7: docker: command not found
rm: cannot remove ‘/var/cache/apt/archives/lock’: No such file or directory
W: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.kurento.org/dists/xenial/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'km6/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
-----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------
ce.com wily/main Translation-en [162 B]
Get:7 https://deb.nodesource.com wily/main Translation-en_US [162 B]
Get:8 https://deb.nodesource.com wily/main Translation-en [162 B]
Get:9 https://deb.nodesource.com wily/main Translation-en_US [162 B]
Hit http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org dist/10gen amd64 Packages
Get:10 https://deb.nodesource.com wily/main Translation-en [162 B]
Get:11 https://deb.nodesource.com wily/main Translation-en_US [162 B]
Hit http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org dist/10gen i386 Packages
Get:12 https://deb.nodesource.com wily/main Translation-en [162 B]
Get:13 https://deb.nodesource.com wily/main Translation-en_US [162 B]
Ign https://deb.nodesource.com wily/main Translation-en_US
Get:14 https://deb.nodesource.com wily/main Translation-en [162 B]
Ign https://deb.nodesource.com wily/main Translation-en
Ign http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org dist/10gen Translation-en_US
Ign http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org dist/10gen Translation-en
Fetched 12.8 kB in 3s (4,015 B/s)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Note that login is succesful (I tried entering in mup.js a wrong password and process stops before all this).

Does anyone have an idea of why I'm getting this error and how to solve this? Do I have to install something on remote server?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run `sudo apt-get -f install` on a remote server?
In my case this command has solved the issue.